# Conditional Statement Not Working Properly in VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, for-loop, conditional-statements, vba

I am writing a code in VBA that loops through every row for several columns and finds the difference between every two rows and stores that value in an array. I added an if statement in the for loop to avoid blank cells being included in the operation, and it works for the first five columns but not for the sixth.

```
Dim Datarray As Variant
Dim LR As Long, LR1 As Long
Dim p As Integer, i As Integer
LR1=LR-1
ReDim R(LR1) As Variant

For i = 1 To DateTime_Column

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
Datarray = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(LR, i))

 For p = 2 To LR1

   If Datarray(p, 1) And Datarray(p + 1, 1) <> Empty Then  
    R(p) = Abs(Datarray(p + 1, 1) - Datarray(p, 1))
   End If

 Next p

Rave = WorksheetFunction.Average(R)       ***Error occurs here because R is empty***

Next i
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with the way my if statement is written? The code seems to think that the cells in the sixth column are empty when they are not. I checked the Datarray and every spot has values in it.

Comment: Shouldn't you calculate `LR` and `LR1` *before* the `ReDim` statement? Right now it appears that `R` is dimensioned to zero elements. Also, adding an `Option Explicit` statement to the top of your code may allow the compiler to flag additional problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `If` statement looks wrong. If you need to check if two conditions are met, use:

```
If Datarray(p, 1) <> Empty And Datarray(p + 1, 1) <> Empty
```